# Saving Files and Sending them to client (NodeJS/Express/MongoDB/Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How do I save some file in mongoose?
For example I have a route for `POST` method `/`, and `GET` method `/`.
Posting to `/` should save sent file to MongoDB database (mongoose), and Getting `/` should send the saved file. If file was an image how do I send it to client as image? (Is it a good practice to save raw file from user, or should I save them in mongodb - if so: how?).

Comment: If possible, I'd suggest you just store images on disk rather than saving it to a database, it is considerably less hassle.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea saving raw images

Answer (score 2):

First it's clear that you should have schema for your `mongoDB`.
You can have it in `SCHEMA.js` file like this:

```
  module.exports = {
         model: function(Schema) {
          return new Schema({
             _id: { type: String, index: true, unique: true },
             updateDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
             data: String
            })
          }
  }
```

then you have for your requests you can do as below:

```
  router.post('/', function(req, res){
     var data = req.body.data;
     SCHEMA = require('/YOUR/SCHEMA/PATH').SCHEMA;

     SCHEMA.update({
       _id: data.id
     }, {
        data: data
     }, {
      upsert: true
      }, function (err) {
       if (err) {console.error('subs-on-userapps> failed update token, err=',err);}
     });
  })
```

In above part you get data form request and then insert it to you mongoDB.

** `.update` first search for you data in first part and with `upsert:true`
option insert data if not exist before.

For have access to your data you have other route with `Get` method so:

```
      router.get('/', function(req, res){

          SCHEMA.findOne({QUERY})
               .execQ()
               .then(function(result) {
                    res.json({result: result})
               });

      })
```

Comment: That's not pretty much that I needed to know...I know how to handle requests or create schemas, I just need to know how to store files sent by users using file input and send them back as raw files not as string data.

Comment: Please see the [GridFs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/) docs for details on storing such binary data.